# Solving two coupled non-linear second order differentially equations numerically

Tags: numerical-methods, differential-equations

I have encountered the following system of differential equations in lagrangian mechanics. Can you suggest a numerical method, with relevant links and references on how can I solve it. Also, is there a shorter implementation on Matlab or Mathematica?

mx (y dot)^2 + mgcosy - Mg - (M=m)(x double dot) =0

gsiny + 2(x dot)(y dot + x (y double dot)=0

where (x dot) or (y dot)= dx/dt or dy/dt, and the double dot indicated a double derivative wrt time.

Comment: Did you want to write mxy'^2 + mg cos(y) - Mg - **(M-m)** x'' = 0 at the first equation?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a vector Y = (x y u v)' so that

```
dx/dt = u
dy/dt = v
du/dt = d²x/dt²
dv/dt = d²y/dt²
```

It is possible to isolate the second derivatives from the equations, so you get

```
d²x/dt² = (m*g*cos(y) + m*x*v² - M*g)/(M-m)
d²y/dt² = -(g*sin(y) - 2*u*v)/x
```

Now, you can try to solve it using standard ODE solvers, such as [Runge-Kutta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge-kutta) methods. Matlab has a set of solvers, such as ode23. I didn't test he following, but it would be something like it:

```
function f = F(Y)
    x = Y(1); y = Y(2); u = Y(3); v = Y(4);
    f = [0,0,0,0];
    f(1) = u;
    f(2) = v;
    f(3) = (m*g*cos(y) + m*x*v*v - M*g)/(M-m);
    f(4) = -(g*sin(y) - 2*u*v)/x;

[T,Y] = ode23(F, time_period, Y0);
```